# TSQL Conditional Where using Temp Tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have a procedure that has takes an XML string of option field data and stores values in temp tables if anything was passed by the user.

For example, if the user selected they wanted to search by `Country` and `Department`, those temp tables would contain data where as `City` would be empty.

What I am trying to do is create a `where clause` that will use the data in those temp tables as its logic.

```
    INSERT  INTO @users(QID)
    SELECT  QID
    FROM    Employees AS e
    WHERE   e.AreaID IN ( SELECT AreaID FROM @areas )
    AND     e.SiloID IN ( SELECT SiloID FROM @silos);
```

In this situation however, if `@silos` was empty, I don't want that to be part of the logic and should include data where the `e.SiloID` is anything.

**Examples:**

### @Areas

1, 5, 7

### @Silos

NULL

Query would be:

```
SELECT QID 
FROM Employees 
WHERE e.AreaID IN ( SELECT AreaID FROM @areas )
AND   e.SiloID = <anything here, we ignore this logic because the temp table was empty>;
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you're looking for: `AND (@silos IS NULL OR e.SiloID IN (SELECT SiloID FROM @silos))`

Comment: Add a variable to store the number of records in variable silos, doing what Santi said above, but with that variable equals zero instead of silos IS NULL.

Comment: @Santi - `@silos IS NULL` IS throws an error when trying to use it in this fashion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each of your where conditions should check if the value is in the temporary table **or** the temporary table is empty. This would create a "conditional filter" that only narrows down results if the temporary table has records in it.

```
INSERT  INTO @users(QID)
SELECT  QID
FROM    Employees AS e
WHERE   ( 
            -- Areas
            NOT EXISTS (SELECT AreaID FROM @areas) 
            OR e.AreaID IN ( SELECT AreaID FROM @areas )
        ) 
        AND ( 
            -- Silos
            NOT EXISTS (SELECT SiloID FROM @silos) 
            OR e.SiloID IN ( SELECT SiloID FROM @silos )
        );
```

Continue this pattern for remaining conditions.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a rowcount variable as others have mentioned in comments, or you can do it inline:

```
AND     (
  e.SiloID IN ( SELECT SiloID FROM @silos)
  OR NOT EXISTS(SELECT SiloID FROM @silos)
);
```

Comment: How could I use this on main first part of my `WHERE` clause as well? Yours is the `AND` for additional field checks but `Areas` is the first thing I look for that I need to apply this same style of logic check on. When I tried 
`WHERE   e.AreaID = ( `, the `NOT` and `OR` operators threw errors.

Comment: Your original question didn't mention that you also wanted the same logic on `Areas`.  It only made this requirement for `Silos`.